# What is this connector in Sensirion cable?

Tags: identification, connector

I have an [evaluation kit from Sensirion](https://www.sensirion.com/en/environmental-sensors/evaluation-kit-sek-environmental-sensing/) which has this connector in the sensor end of the cable:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to mount some sensors in a custom board and install the proper connector to use the same evaluation kit to read the data. Unfortunately in the official documentation there is no information about this connector that I was able to find.

Comment: why are you not asking Sensirion?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the answer, digging into the documentation of other products from this company. The manufacturer code for the male pins for this connector seem to be [850-80-004-40-251101](https://www.google.com/search?q=850-80-004-40-251101&source=lmns&bih=964&biw=1714&client=ubuntu&hs=k01&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJtpfP3aTzAhWY0YUKHZY6DfsQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA).

[image]